# Tmap in R : How can I set hist legend on maps?

Tags: r, tmap

I'm new to working with geographic data, and I'm trying to add a histogram legend with following code.

```
density <-
  tm_shape(density)+
  tm_borders(col = "lightgrey") +
  tm_fill( "counts" , 
           style="fixed", 
           breaks =c(0,1,500,1000,1500,2000),
           palette ="Blues",
           legend.hist=TRUE)
```

I've set the legend.hist to TRUE in tm_fill, but it is still not displaying in the result. My tmap is updated to 3.99.9000. What could the potential problem be?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing what your dataset is like. Bad practice to call the output `density` if your spatial data is also called `density` too. Best to rename that. It could be a/the problem. Maybe you could use the built in dataset `data("World", package = "tmap")`

Comment: I think histograms are not implemented in V4 (3.99.9), see: https://github.com/r-tmap/tmap/blob/80bb9b02eb68c9491d12293bc9fa311eb5e7b0e0/R/tmap_options.R#L481